# c++: Can you call a template instance's function?

Tags: c++

I am looking through some code in ros when I came across the function template `template<typename Stream>`. Later in the function, the instance's method is called like this `stream.next(t.x);` I tried searching, can't find any examples where there are such instances.

Is this possible, and why use templates in this case?

```
namespace ros
{
namespace serialization
{

template<>
struct Serializer<MyVector3>
{
  template<typename Stream>
  inline static void write(Stream& stream, const MyVector3& t)
  {
    stream.next(t.x);
    stream.next(t.y);
    stream.next(t.z);
  }

  template<typename Stream>
  inline static void read(Stream& stream, MyVector3& t)
  {
    stream.next(t.x);
    stream.next(t.y);
    stream.next(t.z);
  }

  inline static uint32_t serializedLength(const MyVector3& t)
  {
    uint32_t size = 0;
    size += serializationLength(t.x);
    size += serializationLength(t.y);
    size += serializationLength(t.z);
    return size;
  }
};

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace ros
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - `stream` is passed in as a parameter and then one of its methods is called. What exactly is unclear about it? Please clarify

Comment: @UnholySheep, I probably isn't too clear about the concepts of templates, so bear with me. As I'm aware, this Stream is a "generic" type, how can I know what functions it has?

Comment: @goh there is no limitations on the functions it could have. You could pass in any type you wanted. But if you try to instantiate the function template with a type that doesn't have a `next` member function that takes a parameter of same type as `t.x` you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: @PeterT, so you mean the compiler will actually check what is exactly passed into the functions, and if the type does not satisfy next(), I'll get a error?   if thats the case, why use templates at all, instead of a base class?

Comment: @goh using a base classe would require everything that you want to pass into the `Serializer` methods to inherit from that class and also to use `virtual` methods. It is one possible way to do it, but using templates doesn't require either inheritance or virtual methods, only for the type to have those methods

Comment: I get it now, thanks guys.

Comment: @goh Using a base class and virtual methods gives you dynamic or run-time polymorphism, using a template gives you static polymorphism that is resolved at compile time. For a more exhaustive explanation see [the four polymorphisms in C++](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/cpp-polymorphism/)